# How to get the value of div tag

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get `MY_TROUBLE_TWO` from it and click?

I have tried below mentioned code, but it didn't get work for me.

Tried code 1)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[7]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[@class='dx-item-content dx-list-item-content']"));
element.click();
```

Tried code 2)

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//div[7]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[@class='dx-item-content dx-list-item-content']"))).click();
```

Tried code 3)

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//xpath_to_item")));
select.selectByVisibleText("MY_TROUBLE_TWO");
```

My `html` code as below:

```
<div class="dx-scrollview-content" onclick="void(0)">
  <div id="50d24777-593c-7626-d924-2a3db0e72e89" class="dx-item dx-list-item dx-list-item-selected dx-state-focused" role="option" aria-selected="true" style="">
    <div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">MY_TROUBLE_ONE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false">
    <div class="dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">MY_TROUBLE_TWO</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error message? Does it timeout? Is it unable to find the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code to get the value of `MY_TROUBLE_TWO`

**Note:** Instead of using an `absolute xpath`, Use `relative xpath`.

**Explanation:** Put some wait before going to the element, For wait I have used `explicit wait` method. After wait find element using `text` method with `div` tag to get the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'MY_TROUBLE_TWO')]")))).click();
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep()`. Instead use `WebDriverWait` and wait for the element to be clickable, etc.

Comment: @JeffC , I use WebDriverWait like this:


`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'SOME_TEXT')]"))).click();`

Comment: @Sergey Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: @Jeffc, Thanks for your reply, I have update my answer with `explicit wait` method.

Comment: I made a small edit to the answer. `wait.until()` returns the element waited for, if successful, so you can just `.click()` the return. It keeps you from having to scrape the page again to click the element.